# Is there an equivalent of using curl with a specified certificate for openssl?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, curl

Is there an equivalent of using `curl` with a specified certificate for `openssl`?

For example, I'd like to achieve the following with `openssl`:

```
curl --cacert test.pem https://vimmi.net
```

I tried:

```
openssl s_client -connect https://vimmi.net -CAfile test.pem
```

But got an error:

```
Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

Comment: `openssl s_client` doesn't implement HTTP, or HTTPS, only SSL/TLS, and thus can't use URLs only a domainname or IPaddress. Use `-connect vimmi.net:443`. Now you have to type a valid HTTP request by hand; see RFCs 7230 and 7231. Since HTTP headers require CRLF but terminal input to a C program like OpenSSL only provides LF, add `-crlf`. Don't make any mistakes, and many servers will disconnect if you don't complete it within a time limit (to block 'slow-loris' attacks); this one appears to allow about 20 seconds.